# How do I manually install the Oracle Java Plugin for Google Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, java, google-chrome, plugins, oracle

How to install Java Plugin to these browsers manually ? I downloaded JRE from Oracle Site, run it in terminal. Now, what I should do ?. I want to do it manually because, I want to be up-date with recent Java version.

Comment: This is a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Matten: Or would that be SuperUser?

Answer (score 3):

For Chromium, add this symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/java/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

For Firefox, add this symlink:

```
sudo ln -s  /path/to/java/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so  /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

replace the `/path/to/java/jre` with the actual path from your installation.

Comment: Can you give the option for chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/java/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

works in google chrome beta.

Answer (score 2):

I copied and updated this answer from @Casey Watson since I can't edit or comment yet.

For **chromium-browser** 25, add this symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/java/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

For **Google chrome** 27,
might need to create the plugins dir:

```
mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

then add this symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/java/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

For **Firefox** 21, add this symlink:

```
sudo ln -s  /path/to/java/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so  /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

replace the /path/to/java/jre with the actual path from your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is quite common. This [thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3ef7b4f7b08118ed&hl=en) may have the answers that you are looking for. Let me know if it helps you out, if not we can discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [how to install Oracle/Sun Java manually in Linux](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=182&t=How_To_Install_Free_PDF_Reader_In_Linux#install_sun_java_runtime_jre_ubuntu_linux).

Answer (score 0):

You may have succeed in enabling the java plugin in firefox by doing something like:

```
sudo ln -s  /path/to/java/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so  /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

It appears that chromium does not look in the /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/ directory, It only checks the ~/.mozilla/plugins  directory.
Therefore to make it work in chromium you also need to do:

```
cd ~/.mozilla/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Answer (score 0):

The information at:

http://ubuntupop.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/install-java-runtime-environment-on.html

fixed my problems.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

open up your "synaptic package manager"  go to settings/repositories then other software,click on the canonical partners, then close and hit the reload button now type "sun java6 plugin" mark it for installation and now hit apply. if you have not done this already you may want to install the "ubuntu restricted extras" but this will install openJDK if you dont want openJDK you can remove openjdk-6-jre-lib by marking for removal and hit apply.